# Is using multiple canvases slower than using one?

Tags: javascript, html, css

If I'm going for fps, is it faster to use one larger canvas and redraw constantly or have a bunch of small canvases and redraw less often but use css3 for animation like this?

```
<canvas id="1" width="60px" height="60px"></canvas>
<canvas id="2" width="60px" height="60px"></canvas>
<canvas id="3" width="60px" height="60px"></canvas>
<canvas id="4" width="60px" height="60px"></canvas>
```

Comment: I have never really seen multiple canvases, which might mean that the best approach is a single canvas.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? A game?

Comment: @Blender: Think of an point-and-click adventure. If the background doesn't have any active objects and the active foreground objects don't interact with the background, it's almost always a better idea to use multiple layers in order to avoid re-rendering of unchanged sections. Instead you can simply clear the uppermost layer and add little sparkles without re-drawing the character, the background, inventory…

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In theory, one canvas would actually be faster, assuming you were to program an algorithm that only redrew what needed to be redrawn, and the redraw method happened all at once*. A redraw method can be one of the most demanding actions a browser can accomplish; the less the better.

However, the amount of code necessary to accomplish such a system probably wouldn't be worth the effort in the end. I would just stick with having multiple canvases for maintainability and extendability purposes.

Here's some other optimization tricks I've learned:

- Clearing an entire canvas does not appear to take any more time than clearing a specific area, and can actually be faster than looping through all the objects and clearing them individually.
- `setTimeout` works best for animations where seeing every frame is important. `requestAnimationFrame` can skip frames on less capable machines.
- Checking to see if an element is in range before attempting to draw it can save CPU cycles, even though the canvas API does this anyway.

*To invoke a single redraw, you can set a canvas `display` to `none`, and then back to `block` after the context has been changed.

Answer (score 1):

Multiple Canvases result in better performance because having just one canvas, it will be sluggish for browsers to draw repeatedly on same canvas than having many canvases and doing the job of drawing simultaneously. Say if you have to redraw on the same canvas you would have to update the surface every time you draw something new. and obviously that would not be the case if you have multiple canvases as you can always draw irrespective of what other canvases are up to.

[CANVAS PERFORMANCE](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/canvas/performance/)